# Issue iterating through values of a previously made function in a new function

Tags: python, function

Here is a function that computes the cubics of numbers from 1 to n.

```
def cubics(n):
    """Compute the cubics of numbers from 1 to n, such that the 
    ith element of the returned list equals i^3.
    
    """
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    if n >= 1:
        cubelist = [i**3 for i in range (1, n +1)]
        return cubelist
    else:
        raise ValueError('Error')
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

I need to create a new function that uses my cubics function to compute the sum of cubics of the numbers from 1 to n. Here is what I have tried so far and am having issues with.

```
def sum_of_cubics(n):
    """Compute the sum of the cubics of numbers from 1 to n."""
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    sum = 0
    for i in cubics:
        sum += cubics([i])
    return sum
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

Thank you for any help. I know I can't iterate through a function, but I am totally stumped.

Comment: In that case, you have to only cube the number, not the numbers between 1 and n

Comment: Your `cubics` function already returns a list of cubes from 1 to n. Your `sum_of_cubics` function should be a single line: `return sum(cubics(n))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function:

```
def cubics(n):
```

Returns a list of numbers cubed. In that case, your function `def sum_of_cubics(n):` can be:

```
def sum_of_cubics(n):
    return sum(cubics(n))
```

Also, note that `sum` is an in-built function. So please refrain from using in-built functions as variables

Answer (score 1):

- If you must iterate through a function, you can try to use `iter` or `yield`

#### code:

```
def cubics(n):
    """Compute the cubics of numbers from 1 to n, such that the 
    ith element of the returned list equals i^3.
    
    """
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    if n >= 1:
        cubelist = [i**3 for i in range (1, n +1)]
        return iter(cubelist)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Error')

def sum_of_cubics(n):
    """Compute the sum of the cubics of numbers from 1 to n."""
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    sum = 0
    for i in cubics(n):
        sum += i
    return sum

print(sum_of_cubics(5))
```

#### result:

```
225
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `for` loop to call the `cubics` function with the value `n`. This will return your `cubelist`, so you are iterating through that. On successive iterations, `i` will be set to 1, 8, 27, etc.

Then you just add `i` to your running total (and like burningalc says, call that something different from `sum`). So your second function becomes:

```
def sum_of_cubics(n):
    """Compute the sum of the cubics of numbers from 1 to n."""
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    total = 0
    for i in cubics(n):
        total += i
    return total
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you are calculating sum which is sum += cubics([i]). What we want is to add each element in the resulting list of cubics(), but in your given program we are not getting the elements in the resulting list. To get the inteneded result you can assign the resulting list of cubics to another variable('res' in my case), and then add each element of res to the sum.

```
def cubics(n):
    """Compute the cubics of numbers from 1 to n, such that the 
    ith element of the returned list equals i^3.
    
    """
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    if n >= 1:
        cubelist = [i**3 for i in range (1, n +1)]
        return cubelist
    else:
        raise ValueError('Error')
    raise NotImplementedError()

def sum_of_cubics(n):
    """Compute the sum of the cubics of numbers from 1 to n."""
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    sum = 0
    res = cubics(n)
    for i in range(len(res)):
        sum += res[i] 
    return sum
    raise NotImplementedError()

n = int(input("Enter the range: "))
print(cubics(n))
print(sum_of_cubics(n))
```

There can be much more optimized versions of this code, I just did it in more elaborate manner.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built-in function `sum` to help to add up all the elements in a list and return the total sum.

so your function can simply be

```
def sum_of_cubics(n):
    return sum(cubics(n))
```

and you can also shorten the code by using `lambda`

```
sum_of_cubics = lambda n: sum(cubics(n))
```

notes, you should never use reserved words as your variable names, and one of them is `sum`

Comment: Unfortunately when I tried this, it still came up with the error. The fix to this code is what @selcuk said above. "return sum(cubics(n)". Thank you much!

Comment: Fixed the code to fit the question, thanks for pointing out the mistake

Comment: Please don't use `lambda` instead of a `def`. It is not pythonic and also violates [PEP-8 recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): _"Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier"_.

Answer (score 0):

Your Cubelist takes an arguement of integer whereas in sum_of_cubic function, there is no need to iterate(no need for a 'for' loop). and cubics take an integer arguement wehereas you gave list.

```
def sum_of_cubics(n):
"""Compute the sum of the cubics of numbers from 1 to n."""
# YOUR CODE HERE
sum = 0
list_cubes = cubics(n)# Give an integer over here not a list
'''You can either use sum function or iterate through the returned list if cubics'''
'''
for k in cubics(i):
    sum+=k
'''
# Sum it up
for k in list_cubes:
    sum+=k
if sum>0:
    return sum
raise NotImplementedError()
```